# can we get iPhone earphone jack plugged in/out event while application is running in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio-player, background-foreground

I want to perform some event when user plugged in/out earphone in iPhone only application is running in background. Simply explanation, I am running music player in background with earphone plugged in, now after some time I am removing earphone (plugged out), at that time I want to show alert "Earphone Plugged Out".

In foreground, we can get this event, that I researched and got, but if we are running the application in background can we get this plugged in /out event?

Comment: No, you can't do this when your application is in background.

Comment: @Dishant can share a sample code or explain how did you fire the headphone play/pause button action when app is in foreground. How ever I am able to get the events when app is in background.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to get event in background while if you app is active, you will get notification. please look on apple docs for more detail.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to due that, since you have the AudioSession running for backgeround mode you will recieve the jack unplug notification.

But You can't show a `UIAlertView` you will have to scheudule a `UILocalNotification` with the current date as firedate. How ever I as an user will find it very anyoing if an app fires an notification to alert me of an action I performed.